# Iterating via loops to make multiple widgets and make the below code better

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, widget, label

I'm pretty new to Python and have written my first ever program with a GUI and have been reading a lot about code to loop your way into creating multiple widgets but haven't seen a solution for my code below.

I have written a program that simulates a tennis match and have created a GUI for the program which consists of  GUI in the form as a Livescoreboard.

For the scoreboard I have createad a lot of labels that will contain the different scores and the players names etc like a real tennis scoreboard and I've also made a few buttons.

My code below is the two methods in which I create and update all the widgets in the GUI. Looking at it, from a novice perspective, it doesn't seem to be the best way of writing this code.

Have been searching and trying to come up with something else than this but haven't found any.

Is there a way to this better or is it fine the way it is?

```
    # Creates the widgets in the GUI.
    def create_widgets(self):
        # Images
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'Federer.gif')
        label = tk.Label(self, image = photo)
        label.image = photo    
        label.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'Rolex.gif')
        rolex_label = tk.Label(self, image = img)
        rolex_label.image = img
        rolex_label.grid(row = 0, column = 3, columnspan = 2)

        # Creates and sets some StringVar()
        self.set_1_player_1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.set_1_player_2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.set_2_player_1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.set_2_player_2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.set_3_player_1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.set_3_player_2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.spelare_1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.spelare_2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.sets_player_1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.sets_player_2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.games_player_1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.games_player_2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.points_player_1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.points_player_2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.show_score_by = tk.StringVar()

        self.spelare_1.set(self.prepared_match.get_player_1().get_name())
        self.spelare_2.set(self.prepared_match.get_player_2().get_name())
        self.sets_player_1.set('0')
        self.sets_player_2.set('0')
        self.games_player_1.set('0')
        self.games_player_2.set('0')
        self.points_player_1.set('0')
        self.points_player_2.set('0')
        self.show_score_by.set(None)

        # The labels
        tk.Label(self, font = "Purisa 8 bold", text = 'Set 1', height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        tk.Label(self, font = "Purisa 8 bold", text = 'Set 2', height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        tk.Label(self, font = "Purisa 8 bold", text = 'Set 3', height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        tk.Label(self, font = "Purisa 8 bold", text = 'SETS', height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 0, column = 5)
        tk.Label(self, font = "Purisa 8 bold", text = 'GAMES', height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 0, column = 6)
        tk.Label(self, font = "Purisa 8 bold", text = 'POINTS', height = 2, width = 15, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 0, column = 7)

        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.set_1_player_1, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.set_2_player_1, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.set_3_player_1, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        self.name_player_1 = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.spelare_1, height = 2, width = 18, relief = tk.RAISED)
        self.name_player_1.grid(row = 1, column = 3, columnspan = 2)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable =  self.sets_player_1, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 1, column = 5)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.games_player_1, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 1, column = 6)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.points_player_1, height = 2, width = 15, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 1, column = 7)

        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.set_1_player_2, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.set_2_player_2, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.set_3_player_2, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        self.name_player_2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.spelare_2, height = 2, width = 18, relief = tk.RAISED)
        self.name_player_2.grid(row = 2, column = 3, columnspan = 2)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.sets_player_2, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 5)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.games_player_2, height = 2, width = 6, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 6)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.points_player_2, height = 2, width = 15, relief = tk.RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 7)

        tk.Label(self, font = "Purisa 8 bold", text = 'Show score by: ', height = 2, width = 15).grid(row = 0, column = 8, padx = 50) 

        # The buttons
        self.play_button = tk.Button(self, bd = 5, text = 'Play', command = self.play, height = 2, width = 10, relief = tk.RIDGE)
        self.play_button.grid(pady = 10, row = 3, column = 3, columnspan = 2)
        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, bd = 3, text = 'Quit', command = self.quit, height = 1, width = 5, relief = tk.RIDGE)
        self.quit_button.grid(row = 5, column = 3, columnspan = 2, pady = 5)
        self.restart_button = tk.Button(self, bd = 4, text = 'Restart', command = self.restart, height = 1, width = 7, relief = tk.RIDGE)
        self.restart_button.grid(row = 4, column = 3, columnspan = 2, pady = 5)

        self.pause_button = tk.Button(self, text = 'Pause', command = self.pause, height = 1, width = 5, relief = tk.RIDGE)   
        self.pause_button.grid(row = 3, column = 8, sticky = tk.S)                                                        

        tk.Radiobutton(self, command = self.show_score, text = 'Point', variable = self.show_score_by, value = 'Point', height = 1, width = 10).grid(row = 1, column = 8, padx = 50, sticky = tk.S)
        tk.Radiobutton(self, command = self.show_score, text = 'Game', variable = self.show_score_by, value = 'Game', height = 1, width = 10).grid(row = 2, column = 8, padx = 50)
        tk.Radiobutton(self, command = self.show_score, text = 'Set', variable = self.show_score_by, value = 'Set', height = 1, width = 10).grid(row = 3, column = 8, padx = 50, sticky = tk.N)

    # Updates the widgets in the frame.    
    def update_widgets(self):
        self.sets_player_1.set(self.prepared_match.get_sets()[0])
        self.sets_player_2.set(self.prepared_match.get_sets()[1])
        if self.prepared_match.show_score_by in ['Point', 'Game', None]:
            self.games_player_1.set(self.prepared_match.get_games()[0])
            self.games_player_2.set(self.prepared_match.get_games()[1])
        if self.prepared_match.show_score_by == 'Point':
            self.points_player_1.set(self.prepared_match.get_real_score()[0])
            self.points_player_2.set(self.prepared_match.get_real_score()[1])
        elif self.prepared_match.show_score_by == 'Game':
            self.points_player_1.set('0')
            self.points_player_2.set('0')
        elif self.prepared_match.show_score_by == 'Set':
            self.points_player_1.set('0')
            self.points_player_2.set('0')
            self.games_player_1.set('0')
            self.games_player_2.set('0')
        self.set_1_player_1.set(self.prepared_match.get_previous_sets()[0][0])
        self.set_1_player_2.set(self.prepared_match.get_previous_sets()[0][1])
        self.set_2_player_1.set(self.prepared_match.get_previous_sets()[1][0])
        self.set_2_player_2.set(self.prepared_match.get_previous_sets()[1][1])
        self.set_3_player_1.set(self.prepared_match.get_previous_sets()[2][0])
        self.set_3_player_2.set(self.prepared_match.get_previous_sets()[2][1])
        if self.prepared_match.match_is_ended():
            if self.prepared_match.get_sets()[0] == 2:
                self.name_player_1.config(fg = 'red')
            else:
                self.name_player_2.config(fg = 'red')
        self.update()
```

Comment: This question would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but it would be useful to see the whole code (including whatever the `prepared_match` is) to give some context. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of setattr (and as you made a class, the __ setattr __ method). You can refactor a lot of your code but you'll find hereunder optimizations your initialization code :

You can create a method like :

```
def create_scoreboard(self, n_players, n_sets):
    """ Create attributes set_X_player_Y """

    for player in range(1, n_players+1):
        for set in range(1, n_sets+1):
            self.__setattr__(
                "set_%d_player_%d" % (set, player),
                tk.StringVar()
            )

        for attribute in ['sets', 'games', 'points']:
            self.__setattr__(
                "%s_player_%d" % (attribute, player),
                tk.StringVar(value='0')
            )
```

Then you can loop over players, sets, etc.

However, the best approach would be to create player objects to store their scores. You can try to isolate objects using a "natural" approach and creating a scoreboard object, players, gamepads (for your buttons), etc.

Comment: What does "set_%d_player_%d mean. I'm not familiar with the percentage sign in python.

Comment: it's a formatting operation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for strings (%d is a number, %s a string, ...) So setattr will create an attribute named set_1_player_1.... I edited the answer as there were loop errors !

Comment: But again, I really think that creating specific objects would be a better option

Comment: I see. But what approach should I use when creating the labels, I have a lot of values differing from each label.

Comment: You can regroup your labels in one resource object so it is easily maintainable. For exemple, you can have a dict like {'player_label' : {'font': 'Purisa 8 bold', 'text': 'Player', ...}, 'score_board' : {...}}